# Clojure: Produce list of all data in sub map

Tags: clojure

I have a data structure as follows:

```
(def data {:node {:subnode 'a}, :node2 {:subnode2 'b, :subnode3 'c} })
```

I want to produce a list of the values of the top nodes (keys), i.e. the subnodes (vals), like this:

```
(:subnode 'a, :subnode2 'b, :subnode3 'c)
```

How can I do this? Pretty much everything I've tried so far produces:

```
({:subnode 'a} {:subnode2 'b, :subnode3 'c})
```

Where all the values are separated.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. "I want to produce a list of the top nodes (keys), i. e. subnodes (vals)" - which one is it? You can `(mapcat val ...)` to produce the second datastructure.

Comment: (flatten (mapcat val data)) has given me what I wanted, thanks. Basically I have a nested map structure - I want to get all the nested key-value pairs (:subnode 'a and so on) in their own list. The new list will not contain the top nodes (:node, :node2), but rather their values, which are the subnodes. The problem I was having was that I kept ending up with the top node values as individual elements ({:subnode 'a} is one element, then {:subnode2 'b, :subnode3 'c} is the next element, whereas I want (:subnode 'a, :subnode2 'b, :subnode3 'c).

Comment: If you like @PiotrekBzdyl 's answer, be sure to accept it!  :)

Comment: I'm sorry that my suggestion was incorrect. You are correct in that it does not produce the list structure but a list of key value pairs which you could reduce into a map again. However that makes more sense from my experience given that I don't see why you would want keys and vals interleaved in a list instead of a map. Also observe that `flatten` operates recursively, so if you have sequences or nested sequences in your subnodes they will all be flattened. Not sure if that is what you want. @Touchdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extract values of each of the top level map and then `flatten` it:

`(flatten (mapcat second data))`

Alternatively to avoid deep fattening done by `flatten` (as noted by Leon Grapenthin) you can use solution provided by jmargolisvt or use `concat`:

`(apply concat (mapcat second data))`

Comment: That seems to give me the same result as before:

Comment: Thanks, that worked, as does (flatten (mapcat val data)). mapcat is what I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

If you `apply` `conj` to your `map`, you'll get them all in one map:

```
user=> data
{:node {:subnode a}, :node2 {:subnode2 b, :subnode3 c}}
user=> (apply conj (map val data))
{:subnode a, :subnode2 b, :subnode3 c}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are library functions `vals`, to collect all the map's vals, and `merge`, to merge maps:

```
user> data
{:node {:subnode a}, :node2 {:subnode2 b, :subnode3 c}}
user> (apply merge (vals data))
{:subnode a, :subnode2 b, :subnode3 c}
```